# Программное нажатие на кнопку на сайте

Tags: java, html

Есть страница сайта с формой для заполнения и кнопкой , которая осуществляет поиск по слову, написанному в этой форме.
Вопрос. Как программно нажать на эту кнопку, а после поиска скопировать url получившейся страницы. (все это нужно сделать в java)
Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй библиотеку [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). В ней ты сможешь сделать такое